# How to get setting from separate file?

Tags: ajax, parameter

I writing a wordpress plugin, that connects to external database and fetch data. Also it create custom button for vitual editor. By clicking this button modal window has been opened, and after that I load form to this window by ajax.

I created php-file as handler for ajax requests. I need to get options from wordpress database, but I have no idea how to do it. if I try just include main file of plugin to the my handler I've got Internal server error 500...

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer:** *Don't* add a separate PHP file for AJAX requests. Declare the functions that will be used in your plugin and load them via `admin-ajax.php`.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_action_name','custom_action_handler');
// to make AJAX action available for non-logged in users:
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_action_name','custom_action_handler');

function custom_action_handler() {
    global $wpdb;

    // optionally keep the actual functions separately
    // include(dirname(__FILE__).'/ajax-handler.php');
    // custom_ajax_handler_process(); // handle request

    // or just handle request here

    exit;
}

$endpoint = admin_url('admin-ajax.php').'?action=custom_action_name';
```

WordPress will automatically take the `action` and match it to the `wp_ajax_` (and/or `wp_ajax_nopriv_`) hook suffix to load the hooked function (`custom_action_handler`).

**Complex answer:** you *can* have a separate PHP file to handle the AJAX requests, but you need to be able to load the WordPress functions and classes you need (eg. for `$wpdb`) within it first. You can do this by:

1. `define('SHORTINIT',true);`
2. Require `wp-blog-header.php` from WordPress root path.
3. Include any needed WordPress includes manually.
4. Process the AJAX request.

Step 3 is the hard part as depending on what you are doing you may need a number of inter-related functions for the file to even load without a `fatal error` crashing your code and thus request response. Though if you are *just* accessing the database functions/class then these may be minimal. Overall this is a doable approach, but may mean much more work for only a slight increase in AJAX response performance time, so probably the simple answer is better.